# All tables open when connecting to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL workbench so I could work on a project. When I connect to my database via the workbench it automatically opens up a query for every table in every schema in my database. The query is just a simple "SELECT * FROM table" but it is generated every time I connect to the database and it takes at least 10 seconds before I can start working and close all the queries. I want to stop this from happening, but I don't know what is the source of this problem. Here is a screenshot of the problem.[image: Query problem]

Comment: I can't remember where workbench stores this info, somewhere in users data; but closing workbench, deleting the files, and restarting it usually fixes it. Just make sure and tabs you want preserved are saved out to sql files. (Search for something like "where does mysql workbench save tabs" to find the exact files)

Comment: Does disabling the "*Save snapshot of open editors on close*" SQL Editor preference have an effect? Or disabling Auto-save?

Comment: Disabling the snapshot feature did the trick. Thanks for the help